# Чем отличается что лучше использовать?

Tags: c#

Скажите пожалуйста чем отличается:

```
Class a;
private void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
   a = new Class(args);
}
```

От:

```
Class a = new Class(args);
private void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e){

}
```

Скажите в чем отличие и что лучше(если есть разница)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос был отредактирован до такой степени, что полностью изменился в сравнении с первоначальным. Отвечу на текущую версию.

Создадим такой класс:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A");
    }
}
```

В классе формы напишем следующее:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ClassA a = new ClassA();

    public Form1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Begin");
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("End");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Load");
    }
}
```

Если теперь запустить приложение, то сообщения выведутся в следующем порядке:

A
Begin
End
Load

Как можно видеть, создание экземпляра `ClassA` было осуществлено в самом начале конструктора формы.

Вообще, выполнить код вне какого-либо метода или свойства невозможно. Дело в том, что компилятор переносит код задания полей класса, наподобие показанного выше, в конструкторы этого класса (причём во все - это важно!).

То есть, вот такой код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    ClassC c = new ClassC();

    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(object someObject)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

на этапе компиляции будет преобразован в такой:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;
    ClassC c;

    public Form1()
    {
        a = new ClassA();
        b = new ClassB();
        c = new ClassC();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(object someObject)
    {
        a = new ClassA();
        b = new ClassB();
        c = new ClassC();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

В итоге код распухает. Поэтому обычно рекомендуется задавать значения полям класса в одном конструкторе и вызывать этот конструктор из других. Приводить код не буду, итак ответ слишком громоздок. Читайте Рихтера.

Так как такой вариант кода выполняется в самом начале конструктора, понятно, что в этот момент сама форма ещё не создана, не существует ещё ни одного контрола на ней. Поэтому код может упасть, если классы `ClassA`, `ClassB`, и т. д. обращаются к каким-либо членам формы.

Отсюда становится понятно, что код, который должен обращаться к уже инициализированной форме, нужно помещать в событие `Form.Load`.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант хуже тем, что не скомпилируется.

А второй - хуже тем, что нестатический член класса недоступен в статическом методе по той же причине, по которой первый фрагмент не скомпилируется, - если Вы планировали использовать `а` в `Main`.

*Update*

Отличие в том, что в первом случае `а` член класса формы, а во втором - локальная переменная в методе `Form_Load`. Что лучше - зависит от того, как Вы собираетесь ее использовать.

Тут слово "лучше" не совсем уместно. Если `а` нужен только внутри `Form_Load`, то он там и должен быть и объявлен и создан. Если он используется в нескольких методах, то объявлен он должен быть как член класса (вне метода), а создан - когда есть все, что нужно для его создания.

Comment: Прошу прощение, я исправил вопрос, хочу использовать именно в winform, а не в консольном приложении. Я просто забыл, что этот код не скомпилится

Comment: А если во втором варианте объявить переменную перед событием? В чем тогда будет отличие? Я в новой правке указал

Comment: @Log1c0 Тогда `а` готово к использованию в любом месте кода формы (например, уже в конструкторе).

Comment: А что тогда лучше использовать первый вариант, то есть создать поле и потом использовать `= new Class` или в начале кода объявить переменную. В любом случае спасибо огромное

Comment: @Log1c0 Если у Вас доступен параметр для вызова конструктора `Class` в теле класса формы, то я бы создавал объект `а` в том же месте, где он объявяется.